# Transpose of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

Q. Let $T:V \to U$ be linear and $y\in U$. If $f\in V^*$ such that $f(y)=1$, then $T^t(f)=\rule{1.5cm}{0.15mm}$

This question was asked in my assignment test.

My Doubt-
I know that $T:V \to U$ is a linear transformation then the transpose is $T^t: U^* \to V^*$,where $U^*$ and $V^*$ are dual spaces of vector spaces $U$ and $V$ respectively.
So $T^t$ should take values from $U^*$ but in the question $T^t(f)$ is required. I guess the question is wrong. Can someone please verify if the question is correct?

Comment: I would strongly suggest writing $A^T$ only for the transpose of a *matrix* $A$ and stick to $f^*$ for the dual of a *linear map* $f$. There is of course a relationship by taking representing matrices and dual bases, but transpose of a matrix and dual of a linear map are still different concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right.  $T^t$ is defined on $U^*$. If $U^* \ne V^*$, then $T^t(f)$ makes no sense for $f \in V^*.$